# Dimensional analysis of particle falling against air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, projectile, drag

I'm trying to solve a question in a sample exam paper. The student is asked to use dimensional analysis to find the time taken for a particle to fall a certain distance when drag is proportional to velocity.

I can get most of the way through it, but I get two possible expressions for the final step and I can't see how to identify the correct one.

Para-phrasing slightly:

> A particle of mass $m$ is released from rest. It experiences a constant acceleration due to gravity $(g)$ and an opposing force equal to $k$ times its velocity.
>
> Use dimensional arguments to show that the time taken to fall a distance $h$ is
> $$T=\frac{m}{k}\,\tau\Big(\frac{k^2h}{m^2g}\Big)$$
> where $\tau()$ is a dimensionless unknown function of a dimensionless quantity.

I can fairly easily show that $T$ must rely on some unknown dimensionless function  of $\Big(\frac{k^2h}{m^2g}\Big)$ and it's obvious that this must now be multiplied by something with the dimension of seconds.

However I see two options:

1. multiply by $\frac{m}{k}$, with dimensions $\frac{kg}{kg\,s^{-1}}=s$
2. multiply by $\sqrt{\frac{h}{g}}$, with dimensions $\sqrt{\frac{m}{m\,s^{-2}}}=s$

**How should I identify option (1) as being correct *(and/or option (2) as incorrect)* ?**
Hopefully I'm missing something very obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote the dimensionless quantity $\frac {k^2h}{m^2g}$ by $\gamma$. Then

$\displaystyle \sqrt {\frac h g} = \gamma^{\frac 1 2} \left( \frac m k \right)$

so

$\displaystyle \frac m k \tau( \gamma) = \sqrt {\frac h g} \tau' (\gamma)$

where $\tau(x) = x^{\frac 1 2} \tau'(x)$

In other words, since $\tau$ is an unknown function, the two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: Ahhh - yes that's really clever; and well explained. Thanks!